# Flutter Breadcrumbs?

Tags: flutter, navigation, breadcrumbs

I need a dynamic "back" button on every screen/page that also shows the title of the previous screen.
Navigation is done via global navigatorKey, pushing new routes is not done from a specific screen.
Is this possible with built-in navigator or it needs to be built from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the string you want to display to the constructor of the widget which will be your next page.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
            child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context)
                      .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return Sec('title1');
                  }));
                },
                child: Text('Press here'))));
  }
}

Widget backButton(context, t) {
  return Row(children: [
    Expanded(
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.backspace),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
      ),
    ),
    Text(t,style:TextStyle(fontSize:16))
  ]);
}

class Sec extends StatelessWidget {
  String t;
  Sec(String x) {
    t = x;
  }

  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(leading: backButton(context, t)),
        body: Center(
            child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('Press here to go back'))));
  }
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfueT.png)

Comment: thats one way to do this, but my navigator is not a part of any page, I use redux state management with a global navigator key so I cannot know what page is under the new page.

Comment: My answer is according to the information you provided in the original question.